# Find anagrams in arraylist recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have a Lexicon helper class with Lex.isWord(String word) and Lex.isPrefix(String prefix) methods, but I can't seem to figure out how to complete this method for finding anagrams of the input word.

```
public static ArrayList<String> findAgrams(String sentence) {
```

Any ideas? I think I need a helper method but I'm not sure.

Comment: Show some effort and present what you've tried already. We don't do the "do the code" here.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a solution in [Learn Java-Recursion](https://sites.google.com/site/learnjav/java/recursion).